# Regex match all words including slash

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove all words behind the number.

```
12 - Balloon Cool
1 - I would like to sleep
541 - Sleep is for weak/sheep
```

Currently I 'm using this regex to replace them with empty

```
/ - (\w+( +\w+)*)/
```

It managed to filter some but not for the string with slash.

```
12
1
541sheep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove any thing after space-hyphen-space you can just use:

```
/ - .*$/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ9nO5/1)

Comment: Cool, I'm surprised that the answer is so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

Search: `^(\d+)\s+-.*?`

Replace: `$1`

Comment: If the goal is to retain only the leading digits, the search string should be be just:    `^(\d+)`
so that it also matches lines that don't happen to have whitespace and a dash following the diigits.

Comment: The replace `$1` won't changing anything with that match.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't talking about the **replace** part of your answer.  I was wondering if the `\s+-.*?` might eliminate some matches if the OP doesn't  require space and a dash after the digits.